# How to inject a NSStackView into the view hierarchy?

Tags: objective-c, nsview, appkit, retain, nsstackview

I have an OSX application written in Objective-C.
It displays some `NSView` in a `NSWindow`,
the problem is **I cannot modify its code**. The original model hierarchy looks like this:

```
NSWindow
|---> original NSView
      |---> (...)
```

I'd like to alter the hierarchy as follows:

```
NSWindow
|---> NSStackView
      |---> original NSView
      |     |---> (...)
      |---> some additional NSView (say NSTextField)
```

How can I display both the original `NSView` and the additional `NSView` next to each other, using `NSStackView`?

My current approach was more or less like this (the example is simplified):

```
- (void)createFirstView {
    NSTextField *label1 = [NSTextField labelWithString:@"First view."];
    [_window setContentView: label1];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // I cannot modify this procedure:
    [self createFirstView];

    // I can modify that:
    NSTextField *label2 = [NSTextField labelWithString:@"Second view."];

    NSView *firstView = [_window contentView];
    [firstView removeFromSuperview];
    NSStackView *st = [NSStackView stackViewWithViews:@[firstView, label2]];
    [_window setContentView:st];
}
```

Unfortunately the `NSWindow` after running this code shows only the "Second view" label:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[_window setContentView:st]` calls `removeFromSuperview` on the old content view and `removeFromSuperview` releases the view. `[firstView removeFromSuperview]` and `[_window setContentView:st]` will both release `firstView`.

Solution: replace `[firstView removeFromSuperview]` by `[_window setContentView:nil]`.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // I cannot modify this procedure:
    [self createFirstView];

    // I can modify that:
    NSTextField *label2 = [NSTextField labelWithString:@"Second view."];

    NSView *firstView = [_window contentView];
    [_window setContentView:nil];
    NSStackView *st = [NSStackView stackViewWithViews:@[firstView, label2]];
    [_window setContentView:st];
}
```